# Make Visual Studio 2017 treat <script type="module"> as containing JavaScript?

Tags: javascript, visual-studio, visual-studio-2017, es6-modules

Visual Studio 2017 currently treats `<script type="module">` as plain text.

Here is a [sample project](https://github.com/KeithHenry/VS2017-bug-script-module) with the [issue extant](https://developercommunity.visualstudio.com/content/problem/124992/typemodule-not-recognised-as-javascript.html).

[image: VS2017 syntax highlighting fail]

I've seen custom handling in VS to support `<script type="template-type">` - could this also be applied (through configuration or extension) to make it treat `<script type="module">` as JavaScript?

Comment: It doesn't work in VS 2019 either...

Comment: @SavoPejović Cheers, but MS have closed https://developercommunity.visualstudio.com/content/problem/124992/typemodule-not-recognised-as-javascript.html and I had thought this was fixed. If you can reproduce this still please raise a new bug with MS and update us here.

Comment: Reported it already, waiting for the response. https://developercommunity.visualstudio.com/content/problem/875317/intellisense-doesnt-recognize-js-code-inside-a.html

Comment: Nope, it was ReSharper. VS 2019 supports modules.